# Transmit params with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my views I have a form and trying to update quantity for an order line:

```
<div class="quantity">Quantity</br> 
    <%= form_tag(order_line_path(line.id), method: "patch") do  %>
        <%= number_field_tag 'qty', '1', within: 1...line.book.stock %>
        <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The instance variable in the rest of my view is a collection of order lines, so I cannot use it.

Then I have in my controller the update method:

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  @order_line = @order.order_lines.find(params[:id])
  @order_line.update_attributes(order_line_params)
end
```

And my strong params definition:

```
def order_line_params
  params.require(:order_line).permit(:qty)
end
```

I get this error :

```
param is missing or the value is empty: order_line
```

Could someone please have a look?

Thanks!

Comment: I've had a look. What is the question?

Comment: I've added my error, thanks!

Comment: Add your server log to your question. You'll see that `params` doesn't include a key for `order_line` - which is why you're getting that error. (Because you do `params.require(:order_line).permit(:qty)`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `param is missing or the value is empty: order_line` is that you are using `form_tag` which gives a "flat" params hash.

However this is easily avoidable if you just use `form_with/form_for`.

```
# routes.rb
resources :orders do
  resources :line_items, shallow: true
end
```

---

```
# app/views/order_items/edit.html.erb
# use `form_with(model: @order_item)` in Rails 5
<%= form_for(@order_item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :qty, within: 1...f.object.book.stock %>
  <%= f.number_field :qty,  %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_order_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  # GET /order_items/:id/edit
  def edit
  end 

  # PATCH /order_items/:id
  def update
    if @order_item.update(order_item_params)
      redirect_to @order_item, notice: 'Line updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def set_order_item
      @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:qty)
    end
end
```

But what you're really looking for unless you are doing the update/creation of nested items with AJAX is most likely a combination of [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) which will let the user mass edit the line items:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for(:order_items) do |oif| %>
    <%= f.label :qty, within: 1...f.object.book.stock %>
    <%= f.number_field :qty,  %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # PATCH /orders/:id
  def update
    if @order.update(order_params)
      redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order updated.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(order_items_attributes: [:qty])
    end
end
```

Comment: You can salvage your attempt by using `params.permit(:qty)` instead of `params.require(:order_line).permit(:qty)` but I would'nt bother. Its much easier to just do it the right way.